# what is infragistics netadvantage?

Tags: asp.net, infragistics, netadvantage

What is infragistics netadvantage ? What is it basically related for ?

Answer (score 4):

Netadvantage is the name for the Infragistics third party controls for .Net applications. They have ASP.Net, jQuery, Winforms, Silverlight and WPF controls. They are much like DevExpress, Telerik or ComponentOne.

I think specifically, Netadvantage is the name of one of there packages which contains licenses for a number of (or most of) the controls mentioned above.

Comment: @Sreejesh compared to what? Other vendors? The "default" controls? You can usually trial the controls from all of those mentioned...or have a look at the controls on the information pages. Usually though it is to provide controls that .net doesn't ship with by default or to provide more powerful features over the default controls.

Comment: Saves you a lot of coding but equally they have a steep learning curve and poor documentation

Answer (score 0):

NetAdvantage for ASP.NET gives you a set of UX controls and components that saves you a lot of time coding. 
You can check its [samples](http://www.infragistics.com/products/aspnet/samples) to see what controls that are missing in VisualStudio`s "Default" controls are available.